# Android HttpURLConnection Connectivity Timeout

Tags: android, networking, httpurlconnection

I'm having an intermittent connectivity issue with Android 4.1.2 and 4.2.2 whereby the HTTP stack seems to completely time-out (DNS Lookup and TCP/IP still works I can check that using ADB SHELL).

These connections are failing over GPRS, not over WiFi.

When checking netstat using SHELL I can see that the connections are sat waiting at SYN_SENT, and when inspecting the firewall on the server, we can see that it has responded to the SYN request but hasn't heard anything back from the device. During this outage it seems that all HTTP traffic fails on the device. Exchange no longer works and you cant request any pages using any of the common browsers (Firefox, Chrome), even though the device reports network and you can make  / receive calls.

My application communicates over HTTP and HTTPS and during this outage both fail. POST and GET to my JSON web service, the requests hang and throw:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to mywebaddress.com/1.1.1.1 (port 443) after 10000ms
```

This is expected if it's having trouble connecting as it is respecting the timeouts I have set below with the HttpURLConnection.

The code I use is as follows, located in an Async class. This is often contained in a connection loop, depending on how important the message is. This may be called up to 3 times with a 15 second gap in-between each call.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;

try
{           
    // Uses ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()
    // Returns true, the Android OS reports a connection
    if(myApp.hasNetworkConnection)
    {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)endpoint.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(20000);

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer strResults = new StringBuffer();
        String strLine = "";

        while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            strResults.append(strLine);
        }

        log(strResults.toString());
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    log(ex.getMessage());
}
finally
{
    if(reader != null)
        try
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    if(connection != null)
    {
        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this in the past, is the method of regularly trying the connection the wrong approach and exhausting the connection pool?

The connections that are created fire regularly and it doesn't (currently) batch connections together.

Just to share a bit more info, this is what netstat shows on the device (ADB Shell) when we experience the outage. The two "ESTABLISHED" connections are TCP connections not HTTP requests. The mobile has signal and the data symbol is showing a connection.

[image: SYN_SENT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I would update, in-case this issue is experienced by anyone else.

The problem here is not with Android but the web service that the application is calling. Looking at it, when it was calling the JSON web service, it was taking far longer than expected (up to and over a minute) to return a response (if at all) and that response was always 200/OK.

As we were saturating the Android HTTP Stack with requests, eventually they were not clearing in a good enough time and would freeze up the device.

I added better fault tolerance to my code by setting the connect and read timeouts to more appropriate values rather than "0" (infinite) and we have looked at modifying the web service so that long running processes return a 201/Accepted status so that the device can carry on doing it's own work. We call the device back by other means (Google Cloud Message) once server processing has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

  try {
   HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
   con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

   con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds

   return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
} catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
   return false;
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, what's the purpose of adding setFollowRedirects? It doesn't seem that from the current responses the server is redirecting anywhere. 

Additionally, setRequestMethod will just return the status code. Much more efficient but is there any other reason?